# Nothing being written to php file

Tags: php

I'm trying to write to a php file but nothing is written to file. I'm using php 7. I have 2 files, index.php, and comments.php (file attempting to write to). The permissions for comments.php is set to 777.

When I cat the comments.php file it is empty and no new content is added to the index.php page.

```
<?php
        if($_POST) {
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $comment = $_POST['comment'];
            $handle = fopen("comments.php", "a");
            fwrite($handle, "<b><i>" . $name . "</b></i> said:<br />" . $comment . "br /><br />" );
            fclose($handle);
        }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Rolling Log</title>
        <meta charset="uft-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Post a change mgmt comment</h1>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            Name: <br /> <input type="text" name="name"> <br />
            Comment: <br /> <textarea rows="10" cols="30" name="comment"></textarea> <br /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Post comment">
        </form>
        <hr>
        <h1>Other CM Comments</h1>
        <?php
            include "comments.php";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is `var_dump($_POST);` inside your `if` condition?

Comment: Also, what is `var_dump($handle);`?

Answer (score 0):

I put this on my server, and it works as expected.  This tells me that the problem is not in your code, except that this line:

```
fwrite($handle, "<b><i>" . $name . "</b></i> said:<br />" . $comment . "br /><br />" );
```

Should look like this:

```
fwrite($handle, "<b><i>" . $name . "</b></i> said:<br />" . $comment . "<br />" );
```

The directory should be owned by the user running your webserver.  In my case, this is apache.  The directory containing the index.php file should be executable by this user, as well, or it won't be able to write anything.

Let me know if you've tried looking at these things and if it helps.  I'll see what else I can think of.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback but after digging all the server logs I saw that SELinux was blocking writing to the file.